# How are jasmine and basmati rice related, how are they different?

Tags: flavor, rice

While I really like to eat rice,
I did not spend much attention on the kind of rice I was eating - up to now.

Actually, I'd probably confuse basmati and jasmine rice...

Obviously, I'm now curious about every aspect of them,

both **the academic**, the biology and history,

and **the emotional** - can the taste be compared? Which cultures prefer which one?

Comment: Hello Volker. I edited your question to remove your request for preference as we do try to avoid poll questions that ask for opinion-based answers. Because you did ask, I will say in this comment that I much prefer basmati as I find jasmine too fragrant and thus less versatile. But again that is just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, my idea was to disclose the preference so the reader can ignore the opinion bias - assuming it is impossible to write unbiased about taste.  Thanks for your answer, perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Volker! Please see the pic below and the information found on  [menurice.com](http://www.menurice.com/wp-content/themes/usarice/dl-lib/US_Rice-Part2.pdf) . Way too much to copy - 9 pages - but there is a ton of great information about rice.

[image]

Comment: Does using the prefix "U.S." imply that the names are not used consistently around the world?

Comment: No, it should mean that is is grown in the U.S. Back in the late 1990's there was a major dispute between the U.S. and India when the U.S. patent office granted a patent to RiceTec. Basmati originates in India and Pakistan and it was said that the patent violated the Geograpical Indications Act. It was resolved when the patent was narrowed to just a few varieties, therefore not hurting the exports from India.

Comment: Oops... forgot to add a section for "legal aspects" in the question... ;)

Comment: Some products sold as basmati are not (or mixtures with other rice cultivars) or are of bad quality (smell more moldy-musty than like basmati when cooking), so get some from a reputable brand (eg Tilda) to compare. Also, cooking instructions on some packs are BS. A rice cooker cup (160-180ml, I shall abbreviate it rc) is useful with or without a rice cooker. 1 rc rice + 1 rc water plus 1/2 rc water independent of amount of rice seems to scale well up to a couple rc rice in both pot (start cold, 12 min on slow flame after boil, rest 20-30 min on hob which is off) and cooker for both types.